# Is there a way to read from clipboard in popup in manifest v3 chrome extension development?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am creating a chrome extension and have built it out with React. When a user submits a form I want to give them an option to use what is already in their clipboard as a value. I cannot seem to find any documentation for accessing the clipboard in an extension for v3 (the newest version). Moreover, I may be misled trying to achieve this in my popup perhaps this should be in the background but i am not sure. Any help would be great

I have tried scouring the internet but there really aren't any solutions I can see for manifest v3.

Comment: [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API)

Comment: The API [won't work](https://crbug.com/1337152), but you can use the classic method via document.execCommand + textarea + clipboardRead permission.